# Can I enable Bluetooth on a Lenovo E520 running Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, thinkpad

I downloaded [this driver](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-edge-laptops/thinkpad-edge-e520/downloads/DS014997), but Windows blocks the setup from running saying it's incompatible.

Are there any way to get Bluetooth running on this computer?

Comment: Does your laptop have a bluetooth module? Did it ever work?

Comment: It is blocking the driver for good reason.  Even if you installed it, the driver, does not support Windows 10.

Comment: Moab: It was installed when the computer still ran Windows 7. I remember trying it, and maybe it has worked at some point, but usually rather bad. Ramhound: Since both Windows 8 and 10 is built on the same core as Windows 7, it is not uncommon that Windows 7 drivers work on the newer versions of the OS even though they are not specified to do so. Incidentally, I just had to install a separate driver to get the memory card reader to work after upgrading the OS. That driver was also specified to run on Windows 7, with no mention of 8 or 10, but it worked brilliantly all the same.